Can't create a store with Medusa v2
This is the command I tried to execute:
npx create-medusa-app@preview
And this is the error that I get:

I have already tried to clean my cache with the following command:
npm cache clean --force
However, that didn't work unfortunately. Can someone perhaps help me? Thanks in advance.

Turns out I had two different Node.js versions on my computer, after deleting the older one, everything worked fine.
